# ¿Cómo le asigno un nombre en una celda en función de como empiece un texto?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo en SQL una base de datos de facturas, el nombre de las facturas comienza con la referencia del tipo de servicio y la ciudad donde se hizo la factura, y estoy tratando de hacer que en las dos columnas de al lado aparezca el tipo de evento y nombre del sitio:

Las columnas que tengo son:
Facturas, tipo, lugar y fecha

Les pongo un ejemplo:

Factura
EvenSEVILLA_10092021
EvenMADRID_23092021
CenaMADRID_20092021
.....

Lo mismo con varias ciudades más y servicios.

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

He probado con la siguiente formula sin éxito:

```
Select * Fom [dbo].[Facturas2021]
IF Facturas starts with 'Even' tipo = 'Evento'
IF Facturas starts with 'Cena' tipo = 'Cena'
...
IF Facturas contains 'Sevilla' Lugar = 'Sevilla'
IF Facturas contains 'Madrid' Lugar = 'Madrid'
```

Este código me da error, por lo que estoy buscando otra solución.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Deberías usar [`CASE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para filtrar y generar un campo con eso, te falla porque tienes mal estructurada la query

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante importante definir el escenario, no con palabras, sino con datos, porque lleva a bastantes errores.

En el enunciado parece que te refieres a columnas que tienes, pero luego parece que te refieres a columnas que quieres. Además `Sql Server` es bastante **delicado**, en el tratamiento de cadenas. Por tanto para obtener una respuesta buena, es necesario que el escenario sea bueno. Y no lo es.

Una posible solución.

```
Create table facturas2021 (facturas varchar(100))
go
Insert into facturas2021 (facturas)
values
('EvenSEVILLA_10092021'),
('EvenMADRID_23092021'),
('CenaMADRID_20092021');
go
```

Fíjate que yo pongo la definición de la tabla y una pequeña sentencia de insert con la que voy a trabajar, para obtener el resultado esperado. (Muy mejorable, pero al menos un inicio).

Esa es una parte superimportante, para aportar una respuesta que tenga valor.

```
Select facturas
     , CASE
           WHEN Left(t.facturas, 4) = 'Even' then 'Evento'
           WHEN Left(t.facturas, 4) = 'Cena' then 'Cena'
       END As tipo
     , CASE
           WHEN PatIndex('%SEVILLA%', T.facturas) > 0 THEN 'Sevilla'
           WHEN PatIndex('%MADRID%', T.facturas) > 0 THEN 'Madrid'
       End as Ciudad
     , Right(t.facturas, 8) as fecha
       from facturas2021 AS t;
```

[image: Resultado]

Las columnas pueden mostrar un valor condicionado al contenido de la información, que tenga la fila que está manejando en ese momento.

En el ejemplo, si la parte izquierda del valor que tiene `facturas` (los 4 primeros caracteres) son iguales a determinada cadena, entonces la salida sera algo. Y así puedes indicar otra evaluación...y otra y otra....y puedes también añadir un else. O incluso realizar otra evaluación dentro de la resolución de una.

```
Case when Expresion THEN Case when Expresion Then xxxxx End -- segundo case
     When Expresion THEN yyyy End --primer case
```

El contains, podría ser la función `patIndex` donde se evalúa la repetición de un patrón y nos devuelve la posición por tanto si lo ha encontrado, será mayor que 0.

Y la `fecha`, pues por los datos que has puesto, puede ser la parte derecha del contenido de la columna `facturas`.

Pero claro, no se sabe como es la `fecha`, ni en que formato de salida tiene que devolverla, pues simplemente se devuelve.

Pero existen otras formas de hacer esto, que además habría que proteger, si la columna contiene valores sin fecha, o simplemente blancos o nulos.

En resumidas cuentas, si preparas un escenario mejor, la respuesta simpre puede darte opciones mucho más eficientes.

[patIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Case](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Left](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Right](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)